# Does the XLSReader from JXLS close the workbook?

Tags: java, excel, resources, jxls, resource-leak

I would like to know if the XlsReader class from jxls closes the workbook.
My code is something like this:

```
XLSReader mainReader = ReaderBuilder.buildFromXML(inputStreamXml);
mainReader.read(inputStreamXLS, beans);
```

There's no method like close available in XLSReader. I tried to find some point in the internal code when the workbook is closed but I couldn't find.
This is the internal implementation of the read method:

```
public XLSReadStatus read(InputStream inputXLS, Map beans) throws 
        IOException, InvalidFormatException{
        readStatus.clear();
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputXLS);
        for(int sheetNo = 0; sheetNo < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNo++){
            readStatus.mergeReadStatus(readSheet(workbook, sheetNo, beans));
        }
        return readStatus;
}
```

Sometimes the xls file is locked by the application, since I couldn't find any point in my code where the resource is not released, I wonder if the problem is the jxls. Apparently the XLSReader doesn't close the workbook. My application closes the inputStreams. Does the application also need to close the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLSReader does not close the workbook. The reason is that jxls-reader is rather an old module and at the time of its creation there was no workbook close() method in POI.

Now I believe the method should be used to close the workbook and release the underlying file resources. So it is a good time to raise a bug in [jxls-reader issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-reader/issues?status=new&status=open)

Comment: issue: https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-reader/issues/7/xlsreader-doesnt-close-the-workbook